# MySQL - setting default timezone for a Rails application

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone

I am using this setup in `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
  config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
  config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
```

But when I am deploying the application to the server, I am seeing these warning messages:

```
warning: :database_timezone option must be :utc or :local - defaulting to :local
```

How to fix this warning? Should I add another `config.active_record.default_timezone` with `:utc`?

Rails cannot use the timezone I set above?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-active-record

`config.time_zone` sets the default time zone for the application and
enables time zone awareness for Active Record.

`config.active_record.default_timezone` determines whether to use
Time.local (if set to :local) or Time.utc (if set to :utc) when pulling
dates and times from the database. The default is :local.

So based on this, if you want to override your default timezone to Eastern time, you'd want to do:

```
config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

Let me know if this helps!